# Pipedrive API pagination

Tags: api, pipedrive-api

Anyone knows a better way to show the total count of registers from some request?

https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=a098d7d8d...0a0sd9kjzxm&start=0&limit=2&BETTER_SUMMARY=TRUE

```
pagination: {
      start: 0,
      limit: 2,
      more_items_in_collection: true,
      next_start: 2
},
SUMMARY: {
      total: 666,
      pages: 333
}
```

---

*Edit: The reason for this question is that when you have lots of data to import/process seems reasonable to see how many records did you processed and until when it will be running.*

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you a heads up, Pipedrive has a new Developer Community forum where you can ask questions. 
This question was answered [HERE](https://devcommunity.pipedrive.com/t/parameter-to-show-total-count-of-results/146/2)